# Who handle the roles of a User in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a Rails 6 application where I'm using `Devise` for authentication, `Pundit` for authorization and I added `Active-Admin` because I need a dashboard where admin users manage the content of the app.

Other than `admin`, I have a couple of more roles `president`, `manager`, `guest`. An `admin` can be `president` or `manager`.

I'm little confuse on what to use to implement the roles, with devise? pundit? I do it by hand?

Is it better to unite the User and the AdminUser model `active-admin` created? Because this way UserAdmin users can't log in to the application, only to the dashboard and that is not what I want.

I have seen tutorials where people add an `admin:boolean` column to the users, should I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it better to unite the User and the AdminUser model active-admin created? Because this way UserAdmin users can't log in to the application, only to the dashboard and that is not what I want.

That depends more on your business logic. It may be a good idea to keep your `users` and `admin_users` tables separated; The `users` table will probably need to have a lot of associations with other tables, that will not be necessarily needed by `admin_users`, right?

> I'm little confuse on what to use to implement the roles, with devise? pundit? I do it by hand?

You may define a `role` column in your `admin_users` table, and use that column in pundit policies, for example:

```
class ResourcePolicy
  # ...
  # ...
  # ...
  def update?
    user.admin? || user.president?
  end
end
```

in `AdminUser`, you can do the following:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin?
    role == 'admin'
  end 

  def president?
    role == 'president'
  end 
end
```

There are many other ways to implement that, and they all depend on what you need to achieve.